# C++ boost::geometry::index::rtree left of .select_on_container_copy_construction must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I'm trying to use `boost::geometry::index::rtree` but I get the following error `left of'.select_on_container_copy_construction' must have class/struct/union/ inside file has_member_function_callable_with.hpp`

here is my code:

```
class A;

typedef boost::intrusive_ptr<A> SharedA;
typedef boost::geometry::model::box<Vector2f> Box2D;

namespace boost {
    namespace geometry {
        namespace traits {
            template<typename _Scalar, int _Cols>
            struct tag<Vector<_Scalar, _Cols> >
            {
                typedef point_tag type;
            };

            template<typename _Scalar, int _Cols>
            struct coordinate_type<Vector<_Scalar, _Cols> >
            {
                typedef _Scalar type;
            };

            template<typename _Scalar, int _Cols>
            struct coordinate_system<Vector<_Scalar, _Cols> >
            {
                typedef cs::cartesian type;
            };

            template<typename _Scalar, int _Cols>
            struct dimension<Vector<_Scalar, _Cols> > : boost::mpl::int_<_Cols>{};

            template<typename _Scalar, int _Cols, std::size_t Dimension>
            struct access<Vector<_Scalar, _Cols>, Dimension>
            {
                static inline _Scalar get(Vector<_Scalar, _Cols> const &matrix)
                {
                    return matrix[Dimension];
                }

                static inline void set(Vector<_Scalar, _Cols> &matrix, _Scalar const &value)
                {
                    matrix[Dimension] = value;
                }
            };
        }
        namespace index {

            // apparently necessary:
            template <typename Box>
            struct indexable< boost::intrusive_ptr<Box> >
            {
                typedef boost::intrusive_ptr<Box> V;
                typedef Box2D const& result_type;
                result_type operator()(V const& v) const { return v->getBox(); }
            };

        }
    }
}

class A {
public:
    Vector3f position;
    float distance;

    const Box2D& getBox() const {
        Box2D box(Vector2f(position[0] - distance, position[1] - distance), Vector2f(position[0] + distance, position[1] + distance));
        return const_cast<Box2D&>(box);
    }
}

class Tree {
private:
    boost::geometry::index::rtree<SharedA, boost::geometry::index::rstar<16, 4>> tree;
}
```

output:

```
1>  tree.cpp
1>x\include\boost\intrusive\detail\has_member_function_callable_with.hpp(200): error C2228: left of '.select_on_container_copy_construction' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is 'boost::move_detail::add_rvalue_reference<U>::type'
1>          x\include\boost\intrusive\detail\has_member_function_callable_with.hpp(276) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::container::container_detail::has_member_function_callable_with_select_on_container_copy_construction_impl<Fun,true,>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Fun=std::allocator<boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_leaf<boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators<std::allocator<SharedA>,boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>>
1>          ]
1>          x\include\boost\container\allocator_traits.hpp(262) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::container::container_detail::has_member_function_callable_with_select_on_container_copy_construction<const Alloc,>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Alloc=std::allocator<boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_leaf<boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators<std::allocator<SharedA>,boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>>
1>          ]
1>          x\include\boost\geometry\index\detail\rtree\node\node_d_mem_dynamic.hpp(257) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::container::allocator_traits<AllocNode>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              AllocNode=std::allocator<boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_leaf<boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators<std::allocator<SharedA>,boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>>
1>          ]
1>          x\include\boost\geometry\index\detail\rtree\node\node_d_mem_dynamic.hpp(320) : see reference to function template instantiation 'BaseNodePtr boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::create_dynamic_node<BaseNodePtr,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_leaf<Value,Parameters,Box,Allocators,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>>::apply<std::allocator<_Other>>(AllocNode &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              BaseNodePtr=boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_node<boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators<std::allocator<SharedA>,boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag> *
1>  ,            Value=boost::intrusive_ptr<A>
1>  ,            Parameters=boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>
1>  ,            Box=boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>
1>  ,            Allocators=boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators<std::allocator<SharedA>,boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>
1>  ,            _Other=boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_leaf<boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators<std::allocator<SharedA>,boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>
1>  ,            AllocNode=std::allocator<boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_leaf<boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators<std::allocator<SharedA>,boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>>
1>          ]
1>          x\include\boost\geometry\index\detail\rtree\node\node_d_mem_dynamic.hpp(320) : see reference to function template instantiation 'BaseNodePtr boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::create_dynamic_node<BaseNodePtr,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_leaf<Value,Parameters,Box,Allocators,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>>::apply<std::allocator<_Other>>(AllocNode &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              BaseNodePtr=boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_node<boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators<std::allocator<SharedA>,boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag> *
1>  ,            Value=boost::intrusive_ptr<A>
1>  ,            Parameters=boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>
1>  ,            Box=boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>
1>  ,            Allocators=boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators<std::allocator<SharedA>,boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>
1>  ,            _Other=boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_leaf<boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators<std::allocator<SharedA>,boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>
1>  ,            AllocNode=std::allocator<boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_leaf<boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators<std::allocator<SharedA>,boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>>
1>          ]
1>          x\include\boost\geometry\index\detail\rtree\node\node_d_mem_dynamic.hpp(316) : while compiling class template member function 'boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_node<Value,Parameters,Box,Allocators,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag> *boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::create_node<Allocators,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_leaf<Value,Parameters,Box,Allocators,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>>::apply(Allocators &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Value=boost::intrusive_ptr<A>
1>  ,            Parameters=boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>
1>  ,            Box=boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>
1>  ,            Allocators=boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators<std::allocator<SharedA>,boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>
1>          ]
1>          x\include\boost\geometry\index\rtree.hpp(1267) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_node<Value,Parameters,Box,Allocators,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag> *boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::create_node<Allocators,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_leaf<Value,Parameters,Box,Allocators,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>>::apply(Allocators &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Value=boost::intrusive_ptr<A>
1>  ,            Parameters=boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>
1>  ,            Box=boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>
1>  ,            Allocators=boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators<std::allocator<SharedA>,boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>
1>          ]
1>          x\include\boost\geometry\index\rtree.hpp(1267) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::create_node<boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators<std::allocator<_Ty>,boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::dynamic_leaf<Value,Parameters,Box,Allocators,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=SharedA
1>  ,            Value=boost::intrusive_ptr<A>
1>  ,            Parameters=boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>
1>  ,            Box=boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>
1>  ,            Allocators=boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators<std::allocator<SharedA>,boost::intrusive_ptr<A>,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::model::box<boost::geometry::model::point<float,2,boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>>,boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_d_mem_static_tag>
1>          ]
1>          x\include\boost\geometry\index\rtree.hpp(1264) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::geometry::index::rtree<SharedA,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::index::indexable<Value>,boost::geometry::index::equal_to<Value>,std::allocator<_Ty>>::raw_create(void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Value=SharedA
1>  ,            _Ty=SharedA
1>          ]
1>          x\include\boost\geometry\index\rtree.hpp(544) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::geometry::index::rtree<SharedA,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::index::indexable<Value>,boost::geometry::index::equal_to<Value>,std::allocator<_Ty>>::raw_create(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Value=SharedA
1>  ,            _Ty=SharedA
1>          ]
1>          x\src\tree.h(35) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::geometry::index::rtree<SharedA,boost::geometry::index::rstar<16,4,4,32>,boost::geometry::index::indexable<Value>,boost::geometry::index::equal_to<Value>,std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Value=SharedA
1>  ,            _Ty=SharedA
1>          ]
```

I can't find what I did wrong.

Comment: what is Vector2f/Vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that here is bug in boost 1.55.0, upgrading to 1.56.0 (still beta) seems to fix this.

Comment: Yes, there is a bug in Boost 1.55 (in Boost.Intrusive) on msvc-12 (Visual Studio 2013), see: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9332.